# Flexslider + hashing + jquery UI tab conflict?

Tags: jquery-ui, hash, tabs, conflict, flexslider

I'll try explain this the best I can as I am not a developer.

Essentially I am using the jquery UI tabs plugin on my work's site with 3 tabs total. In each one of these tabs there is going to be a flexslider that scrolls through 5 slides.

Also in place is a tab hashing system that has been developed for us allowing to deep link from a URL to individual tab content areas.

The problem I am having is that if someone is directly linked to either the second or third tab, the flex slider on the first tab does not always show it's content. The box is there with the navigation & pagination, but there is physically no content showing. This only seems to happen when linking through to the second or third tab via URL. If you are linked through to the first tab via URL all of the flexsliders work accordingly.

Basically the jQuery tabs needs to work with Flexslider & the URL deep linking. Any advice is appreciated!

This is the JS code I am using:

```
<!-- Tabs configuration -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

// Flexslider configuration (updated 24/02/2014)

var sliderinit = function(t){
    $('#' + t + ' .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        pauseOnAction: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 9000,
        animationSpeed: 500,
        randomize: true,
        animationLoop: true
    });
}

$(window).load(function() {
    sliderinit('tabs-1');
});

$(document).on('click', '.ui-tabs-anchor', function () {
    var t = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');      
    sliderinit(t);      
}); 





//<!-- jQuery Back Button configuration (BBQ) -->

$(function(){
var tabs = $('.ui-tabs'),
tab_a_selector = 'ul.ui-tabs-nav a';
tabs.tabs({ event: 'change' });
tabs.find( tab_a_selector ).click(function(){
    var state = {},
    id = $(this).closest( '.ui-tabs' ).attr( 'id' ),
    idx = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;
    state[ id ] = idx;
    $.bbq.pushState( state );
});
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
    tabs.each(function(){
        var idx = $.bbq.getState( this.id, true ) || 0;
        $(this).find( tab_a_selector ).eq( idx ).triggerHandler( 'change' );
        var t = $(this).find( tab_a_selector ).eq( idx ).attr('href').replace('#', '');         
        sliderinit(t);  
    });
})
$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="flexslider-container">
            <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li id="one"></li>
                    <li id="two"></li>
                    <li id="three"></li>
                    <li id="four"></li>
                    <li id="five"></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- END FLEX SLIDER -->
        </div><!-- END OF FLEXSLIDER CONTAINER -->
</div> <!-- END OF TABS 1 -->

  <!-- TAB 2 -->
<div id="tabs-2"> 
        <div class="flexslider-container">
            <div id="main-slider1" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li id="one"></li>
                    <li id="two"></li>
                    <li id="three"></li>
                    <li id="four"></li>
                    <li id="five"></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- END FLEX SLIDER -->
        </div> <!-- END OF FLEXSLIDER CONTAINER -->
</div> <!-- END OF TABS 2 -->

   <!-- TAB 3 -->
<div id="tabs-3">
        <div class="flexslider-container">
            <div id="main-slider2" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li id="one"></li>
                    <li id="two"></li>
                    <li id="three"></li>
                    <li id="four"></li>
                    <li id="five"></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- END FLEX SLIDER -->
        </div> <!-- END OF FLEXSLIDER CONTAINER -->
</div> <!-- END OF TABS 2 -->


</div> <!-- END OF TABS -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/v5VP4/)** of **flexslider inside jquery-ui tabs**

JS code:

```
$(function() {
     var slider2_initialized = false;
     var slider3_initialized = false;

     $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
         activate: function( event, ui ) {
            //console.log("ui = ");console.log(ui);
            var tab_id = $(ui.newPanel).attr('id');//alert(tab_id);

            if(tab_id == "tabs-2" && slider2_initialized == false)
            {    
                $('#flexslider2').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide"
                  }); 
                //update initialization flag to true
                slider2_initialized = true;
            }
            else if(tab_id == "tabs-3" && slider3_initialized == false)
            {    
                $('#flexslider3').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide"
                  }); 
                //update initialization flag to true
                slider3_initialized = true;
            }
         }
     });

$('#flexslider1').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });   
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>
    <div id="flexslider1">
  <ul class="slides">

  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
<p>
    <div id="flexslider2">
  <ul class="slides">

  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
<p>
    <div id="flexslider3">
  <ul class="slides">

  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
    </div>

</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your response but it needs to be Flexslider as this is what our site uses. Sorry I have editted my question to include that information.

Comment: I made a new working demo with `flexslider` and updated my JSfiddle demo link and the code in my answer. Please let me know if you have any problems